# dhclient does not work in opensuse 42.3, what's wrong?

Tags: isc-dhcpd, dhclient

On openSUSE 13.1 , `dhclient eth0` works well, it re-request an IP address from DHCP server, which cost 1~2 seconds to finish.

[image: dhclient on opensuse 13.1 works well]

**However, with openSUSE 42.3, dhclient always fails instantly.** I don't know what is going on.

[image: dhclient on opensuse 42.3 fails]

It says sth like:

```
/sbin/dhclient-script: unable to pre-init requested interface eth0
/sbin/dhclient-script: unable to pre-init requested interfaces -- see log messages
```

And I don't know where to find that log messages.

Comment: and you should verify the interface name with `ip link`. It's perhaps not named `eth0` anymore

Comment: Sure, I did not make that numb mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug,
some dependency in this script to NetworkManager or so.
If you happen to have a generic script around in /usr/lib/ or so ... point to it via -sf switch.
then the client works as expected.